# How can you upgrade Azure Upgrade A-Series VM to D-Series VM?

Tags: azure, server, virtual-machine

The most recent information I could find while scouring the net was a post 6 months old (back toward the original deployment of D-Series servers). How can you seamlessly upgrade an A-Series Azure VM to a D-Series Azure VM without a huge headache?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upgrading from A-series to D-series Azure virtual machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27185330/upgrading-from-a-series-to-d-series-azure-virtual-machine)

Answer (score 1):

To find out what sizes are available in your Region (and see the InstanceSize naming sceheme to use in Powershell) use this PowerShell Cmdlet:

```
Get-AzureLocation | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName.Contains("<your-region>")}
```

View the VirtualMachineRoleSizes property to see what sizes you have access to.

To update a VM you can use the following set of commands:

```
Get-AzureVM -ServiceName <cloudservice> -Name <vmname> | Set-AzureVMSize -InstanceSize <sizevalue> | Update-AzureVM
```

If you run the above command on a running VM it will be restarted in order to provision it on the right host infrastructure to support your desired Series.

Comment: So once I have verified that I can upgrade to the D-Series, how can I upgrade (the physical process, not the changing a couple settings process). Is it automatic?

Comment: The second command above will upgrade the host (and cause a restart). No additional work required.

Answer (score 1):

```
# To Upgrade or downgrade your Azure VM Plan you can use the following script

$ResourceGroupName = "CMLAB" 
$VMName = "2007CMCEN" 
$NewVMSize = "Standard_A5"

$vm = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $VMName 
$vm.HardwareProfile.vmSize = $NewVMSize 
Update-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -VM $vm
```